# Receive Json post into a controller from 3rd party application

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, opentok

I have to wrote a method that will receive a json post from a 3rd party site.
and then I will have to convert the json to a model and do some operation.

I am trying  this:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public MyCustomModel GetStatus(string jsonObj)
 {
         ///something goes here..
 }
```

when I call this from fiddler, it never works. Fiddler says

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
```

what am I doing wrong?? Any ideas would be much appreciated..

Comment: Souldn't your method return an ActionResult?

Comment: does it matter in this case? The 3rd party api should call somethinglike: http://0.0.0.0:0000/api/blah/blah

Comment: I didn't know it was an api. In this case, your method should be named Post. Isn't it?

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean...but i have [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")].